# iphone app not working ipad simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My iphone app runs on iphone simulator and devices but not on ipad simulator. It doesnt showing any errors but the application is not launching just blank black screen only displays.

While running in ipad simulator 5 it showing following error "applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

My application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code is as below :

```
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.rootViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
[self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And my main.m code is as below :

```
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

What is the wrong with this???

Comment: when you started your app have you selected an universal app? If yes, have you implemented the iPad views?

Answer (score 1):

Go on the App Target info and set "Target device Family":"iPhone" then it works fine both on iphone and ipad simulator and device both.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change this:

```
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
```

to this:

```
self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: no change... Do i need to do anything in IB bcoz currently my rootviewcontroller outlet doesnt target anything... can this be a reason???

Answer (score 0):

Check....Navigation Controller delegate must have been connected (delegate > AppDelegate) in IB.