# iOS black screen on ipad, not iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, window, screen

I have a problem that I am stuck on for a couple of hours.

I have an iPhone wich successfully made it to the App Store. Now I want it to support iPads aswell.

In order to achieve that I create new XIB-Files for iPad an name them something like this:

iPhone: RootViewController_iPhone.xib

iPad: RootViewController_iPad.xib

Then I set the file's owner propperly.

this is how i call them:

```
MyViewController *vC;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    vC = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
} else {
    vC = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
}
```

Within each viewcontroller I then make some custom layoutfixes depending on the current device family.

This works fine for allmost all my views, exept two of them.
The screen stays black, no matter what I have tried.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128537/ipad-app-only-shows-black-screen-after-updating-to-ios4-sdk), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216336/blank-black-screen-when-running-my-ipad-app), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060422/iphone-app-not-working-ipad-simulator), to list a only a few questions. Apparently I was not able to fix this.

Any ideas why this only happens for (luckily)two of my views?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is some initialization code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));    //frame: {{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];     //no result here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UILabel *l1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 30)];
    l1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    l1.text = @"Zurück";
    l1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    l1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    l1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
    [self.view addSubview:l1];
    [l1 release];
}
```

Comment: i do believe your problem lies within the views themselves...can you give more info on them..

Comment: Have you checked all the links in the nib files? Is the mainView correctly connected to the `view` property? Is the fileOwner set? Are you doing any additional initalising in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I posted some initializationcode. I compared the nib files over and over again, I was not able to find any difference to the other nixs

Comment: Have you connected the view property of your .xib with the actual view? Also make sure you have the MyViewController class set in the .xib's properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this (not leaving bundle nil)

```
initWithNibName:@"RooViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
```

Altough, I don't know if it will help...

Comment: thank you, this was quiet obvious. Unfortunately this didnt change anything